# Neo4j : ACL - distance between principals

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

New to graph databases, and trying to make ACL in Java by using example from Neo4j blog:

[Access control lists the graph database way](http://blog.neo4j.org/2010/02/access-control-lists-graph-database-way.html)

And the problem is in provided ruby code:

```
#Here's our function to check the distance between principals (and to see if they're on the same path at all).
def depth_of_principal( principal, reference_principal )
  result = reference_principal.outgoing( :IS_MEMBER_OF_GROUP ).depth( :all ).path_to( principal )
  return result.nil? ? nil : result.size
end
```

Should i use the shortest path algo in java, or am i getting it wrong? What would be the correct way to port this to java?

```
        PathFinder<Path> finder = GraphAlgoFactory.shortestPath(Traversal.expanderForTypes(RelTypes.IS_MEMBER_OF_GROUP, Direction.OUTGOING), maxDepth);
        Path path = finder.findSinglePath(principal, referencePrincipal);
```

One thing that does not fit is maxDepth, but as i won't have paths deeper than 15, i guess it should be ok?

Comment: Looks good to me. Shortest-Path algorithm also uses the bidirectional traverser, should be the fastest way to find the distance.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, using shortest path for that (since you're indeed looking for the shortest path between those two principals) is appropriate. And you can see the max depth as a safety net here rather, such that your traversal won't go crazy.